# Wrap text inside in a ScrollViewer windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have some text in a ScrollViewer control written in c# code, how do I wrap the text? Any solution?

Initialy I have a pop-up, inside this a stack panel and added

```
ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();
```

In this scroll viewer i put some text.

```
string values[]= new string[]; //(example)
sv.Content = values[1];
```

When I open pop-up, if text length is more than screen size, he need to show scroll bar.

```
 sv.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
```

is possible or something another way?
All items ( scroll viewer, text  ) I puts behind view, not in xaml (view) because my content are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to be able to scroll anything inside a scrollviewer, you have to stop the scrollviewer from growing with the child element.

If this happens dynamically, give the scrollviewer a certain height and the text inside it will be scrollable

Answer (score 1):

Create a `TextBlock`, assign the text to this `TextBlock` and add this `TextBlock` as the content of the `ScrollViewer`

```
var sv = new ScrollViewer();
var tb = new TextBlock
{
    Text  = //your text,
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
}
sv.Content = tb;
```

Comment: Depends on how you use it .. If you want the Scrollviewer to be a specific height, just set it, maybe add I StackPanel to the Scrollviewer and add the TextBlock to this StackPanel .. also dependes on how you insert the Scrollviewer to the rest of you Page / Controll

Comment: To clarify that:

In this case text is in scroll viewer but not warp

 StackPanel sp= new StackPanel();
 popUp.Child = sp;
 ScrollViewer txt2 = new ScrollViewer();//used like a textblock to show some text

 sp.Children.Add(txt1);
 sp.Children.Add(txt2);

In second case text what I need I put inside txt2, if I have some text more than screen size, I want to scroll to the bottom to see.


StackPanel sp= new StackPanel();
 popUp.Child = sp;
 TextBlock txt2 = new TextBlock();//used like a textblock to show some text

 sp.Children.Add(txt1);
 sp.Children.Add(txt2);